# appending script element to the head with javascript doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

in my main page i want to check and if it's not already loaded , include a edit_profile.js script

```
$(function(){


  if (typeof is_editprofilejs_loaded == "undefined") {

       alert('undefined');
       var e = document.createElement("script");
       e.src = base_url+"js/edit_profile.js";
       e.type = "text/javascript";
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);

  }
  else
  {

      alert('its loaded.');

  }



})
```

and in my `script.js` i have

```
   $(function(){
        var is_editprofilejs_loaded = true ;
        alert('now its loaded ! ');
       //some code 
   })
```

so when i run my code in the firefox i get these messages

```
1 - undefined
2 - now its loaded !
```

but in chrome i just get

```
1 - undefined
```

and of course the code in the included page doesn't work 
whats wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked if the script is actually added to the DOM and requested from the server?

Comment: since you are using jQuery, I would try using `$.getScript`. [Here's the documentation on that.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: What is the value of `base_url` ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `document.head` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`?

Comment: @some the `base_url` is `http://localhost/social/` and yes i've tried document.head it's the same

Comment: If `base_url` is the same base as the main document you don't need to specify it. Use it as a relative path.

Comment: @some thanx i'm using mvc framework it doesn't work with relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have those functions in a DOMready function?

This is also the cause of the fail: Your variable `is_editprofilejs_loaded` is local to that anonymous function, and will never be defined in the function at the main file.

- Remove the unnecessary function and/or
- Make the variable explicitly global by assigning `window.is_editprofilejs_loaded = true` and check it via `if (window.is_editprofilejs_loaded)`

BTW, your `script.js` is missing a `);` in the end - not sure if only a c&p mistake

Comment: Hmm... Why should that prevent the file from being loaded? It should always load the file, regardless of if it was loaded before. What am I missing?

Comment: @some If I understand correctly, the file *IS* being loaded, but since the alert message is inside of a `DOMready` function, it is never being executed (the dom is already ready).

Comment: From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): *"If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately."* And the following syntaxes are equivalent: `$(document).ready(handler);`, `$().ready(handler);` and `$(handler);`

Comment: You found a big bug but I'm not convinced that you found the solution to the problem max was asking for. But max has accepted your answer so maybe the problem was solved.